# How to select element within popover-bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

first, I am a very new to jQuery.

I have problem to get select a "select" element when it call via popover bootstrap. I have already tried any possible solution I came across: select element within div tag, etc. But nothing works.

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zMrmL/.

```
var test2 = $('#optionDropdown2');
var test = $('#popoverContent select.optionDropdown'); //I have no idea here

    $(test2).select2();
    $(test).select2();


    $(test).change(function() {
        var theID = $(test).select2('data').id;
        var theSelection = $(test).select2('data').text;
        $('#selectedID').text(theID);
        $('#selectedText').text(theSelection);
    });

    $(test2).change(function() {
        var theID2 = $(test2).select2('data').id;
        var theSelection2 = $(test2).select2('data').text;
        $('#selectedID2').text(theID2);
        $('#selectedText2').text(theSelection2);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
$(document).on('change','#optionDropdown',function(){
  var theID = $(this).val();
  var theSelection = $(this).children('option:selected').text();
  $('#selectedID').text(theID);
  $('#selectedText').text(theSelection);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zMrmL/5/

Answer (score 0):

The select box inside the popover doesn't exist in the DOM until the popover appears.

When you do this:

```
var test = $('#popoverContent select.optionDropdown')
```

the select element doesn't exist yet. Try printing out the test variable and you'll see what I mean. The solution is to retrieve the element only after the popover exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, both of Robert and lashab pointed me the same which is select box will never exist before popover being clicked. I put the function call within popover function and it works.

Here is the new fiddle... just for sake of keep learning http://jsfiddle.net/zMrmL/7/

```
$(document).on('shown', "#btnPopover", function () {
$('select.optionDropdown').select2().change(function() {
var theID = $(this).select2('data').id;
    var theSelection = $(this).select2('data').text;
    $('#selectedID').text(theID);
    $('#selectedText').text(theSelection);
});
});
```